# How to create a connection pool at executor level in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking to share an http connection pool to a third party service in my spark executors.

-It will of course be recreated for each element if I create the connection pool inside the map

```
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool

rdd = sc.parallelize(["peter", "john", "harris"])


def get_service(name):
    pool = HTTPConnectionPool('ajax.googleapis.com', maxsize=10)

    r = pool.request('GET', '/ajax/services/search/web', fields={'q': 'urllib3', 'v': '1.0'})
    return name

rdd.map(lambda x: get_service(x)).count()
```

- I get an error if I create it as a global function
- I could do a map partition and create it inside. I will then get one connection pool by partition (better than nothing but not perfect)

Where should I define my connection pool to have only one by executor ?

Comment: See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd

Comment: @Reactormonk Exactly what I am trying to do. However, in the 4th example (the last one), where should I define my pool? Using urllib3 I need to instantiate it. The example is using a static class to handle the pool and I need to create an instance to manage the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation @ReactorMonk has poitned out defining the connection pool inside of a `foreachPartition` (for just an action) or `mapPartitions` (if you want information back) is a good way to limit yourself to one connection per partition. (Although the link provided was to the streamining docs, so it could have been a little confusing, you may also wish to look at `mapPartitions` in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD)

```py
def processRecords(itr):
    pool = HTTPConnectionPool('ajax.googleapis.com', maxsize=10)
    return map(lambda name: //logic goeshere,
        itr)

rdd.foreachPartition(sendRecords)
```

One optional potential improvement, if you may have a large number of partitions compared to the number of executors is to `coalesce` your data down to have the same # of partitions as executors, reducing the number of connections you will end up making.

If we were in the JVM we could also try and use the singleton pattern on the worker, but things get a little complicated with how the python executors works in Spark.

Comment: In Scala, you can create an object (singleton) with your pool of objects. The pool will be instantiated for each executor and shared by the cores that run on that executor. Not sure how to do this in Python.